# How do you add a trimmed circular button image to your android drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to make a basic media player. I downloaded a free .png from a website for the circular play button but when I just copy and paste it into the drawable folder and add it as my ImageButton I can't scale it down to be the size of my other buttons and the background is gray.

How would I scale the button down and trim out the gray background?

Comment: You can use ImageView instead of ImageButton. Because ImageView has property namely scaleType, in which you have different options for image size.

Comment: you will have to resize the image with another program (like paint) or resize the asset during runtime using Java (Image img = yourImage.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);)

Comment: @aquaballin will android automatically scale the button to people's displays? I'm afraid the image will be too blurry on bigger more high res displays if I scale down the pixels

Comment: The best and quickly solution is @ParthPatel 's one. Since the `ImageView` has `setOnClickListener()` it's the same behavior than a `ImageButton` but with `ImageView`'s property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You can scale the image so that it works on multiple devices by doing something like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
Image img = yourImage.getScaledInstance((width * .10), (height * .10), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);)
```

This is just an example, but it would resize the image so that it is close to a **tenth** of the size.

**2.** Another method would be to simply resize the image with a program like paint, and have the image much smaller. Although this is an immediate easy fix, the image size is not responsive to actual screen size.

**3.** ScaleType attribute is also a means to change size depending on how you are using the image asset in your code. (thank Parth Patel)

Answer (score 1):

I used an ImageView instead which can basically do anything a button can and scaled it down. Looks great, thank you to @ParthPatel for giving me the answer.

Comment: glad you figured it out

Comment: @aquaballin I appreciate your answer as well. It answered the specific question I asked without having to not use the button.